# Eclipse android programming with ultrasonic sensor

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sensors

I was writing my eclipse android (java based) program to read the sensors values on a device , so I am creating a hash map with different sensors I have , but I can't find ultrasonic sensor

```
    sensorTypes.put(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE, "Type_Gyroscope");
```

there are a lot of other sensors but I can't find ultrasonic ? Can you please help me
Thanks

Comment: Which devices have an ultrasonic sensor?

Comment: its a robot , i installed on it an ultrasonic sensor , I want to listen to the ultrasonic sensor reading on my android application